# laravel clean up empty query vars

Tags: laravel

I want to remove empty query vars from a url in my controller. my url is `/search?qi=yoga&q=` notice that q is empty. Sometimes qi will be empty. How can I remove these? Seems like a simple issue, but I can't seem to find a elegant solution.

```
function search() {
    $qi = Request::get('qi');
    $q = Request::get('q'));
    $results = getResults($qi, $q);

    return View::make('search.results', compact('results'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in the next request, but you would have to Redirect::refresh() or Redirect::to($url) with a clean url, like

```
$items = Redirect::query();

$items = $this->removeEmptyItems($items); /// you'll have to create this method!

return Redirect::route('your.current.route', $items);
```

As you can see, this will clean up your url, but it requires a new request.

But this looks like something you have in your current request and I'm afraid Laravel cannot change a URL in the browser for you. If this is a form submission query, Javascript can help you prevent from sending those empty queries:

```
$('form').submit(function(){$('input[value=]',this).remove();return true;})
```

Comment: Javascript to the rescue! I knew it had to be simple. Thanks Antonio.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
function search()
{
  $search = array_filter(Request::all()); // or only(..) / except(..)

  $results = getResults($search);
}
```